# Error in authentication service, Java 21 + Spring Security 6 and JWT

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, nimbus-jose-jwt

I am trying implement an authentication service using a public and private key pair and JWT.

I'm using Java 21 + Spring Security 6 and JWT, but I get an error and the application crashes.

This is my configuration class:

```
...

import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.ImmutableJWKSet;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Value("${jwt.public.key}")
    private RSAPublicKey key;
    @Value("${jwt.private.key}")
    private RSAPrivateKey priv;
    
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
        .authorizeHttpRequests(
        auth -> auth.requestMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults()) 
        .oauth2ResourceServer(
            conf -> conf.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

        return http.build();
    }


    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(){
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(key).build();
    }

    @Bean
    JwtEncoder jwtEncoder(){
        var jwk =  new RSAKey.Builder(key).privateKey(priv).build();
        
        var jwks = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(jwk));

        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwks);
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

This is the erro:

```
...
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed   
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1418) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]      
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]        
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:960) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:464) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1358) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1347) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at br.demo.springsecurityjwt.SpringSecurityApplication.main(SpringSecurityApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'jwt.public.key' in value "${jwt.public.key}"
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:180) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]     
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]  
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:200) ~[spring-context-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:921) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1374) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[spring-beans-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
...
```

This is my application.properties:

```
jwt.private.key=classpath:app.key
jwt.public.key=classpath:app.pub
```

The app.key and app.pub files are both in the /src/main/resource folder. I omitted the value of the keys in this post.

app.key

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
key
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

app.pub

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
key
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

If I change the lines from `@Value("${jwt.public.key}")` to `@Value("${jwt.public.key:classpath:app.pub}")`, I get the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'key': Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey'; Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey] for value [${jwt.public.key:classpath:app.pub]
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: There is no automatic converter, which converts the key into the Object. You have to do it by your own.

Comment: Any example of this converter?

Comment: Usually in java you put key in a keystore after that you can use them. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/6nf1il6er/index.html

Comment: There are several unknowns here and im not going to provide an answer and guess whats wrong. First of all, you dont need `classpath` as _most likely_ your build framework maven/gradle will resolve it. Second what format is your key? Der, Pem, pkcs8? You have omitted the key format, and java can only read specific formats. Lastley are you sure that public/private are not reserved words in application.properties? So as said before, too many unknowns to give an answer here.

Answer (score -2):

The issue might be related to the placeholders not being resolved properly in the `@Value` annotations for `jwt.public.key` and `jwt.private.key`. I will suggest you to try a different approach to load the keys from the classpath.

First, move the keys from the `/src/main/resources` folder to `/src/main/resources/config` to ensure they are placed in a separate directory.

Then, update your `application.properties` file:

```
jwt.private.key=classpath:config/app.key
jwt.public.key=classpath:config/app.pub
```

Now, modify your `SecurityConfig` class to load the keys using the `ResourceLoader`.